# PHP: removing words written in an array from another word

Tags: php

```
$a = array('jo', 'se');
$word= 'josephine';
```

I want to delete all the instances where the words 'jo' or 'se' can be found in the $word. So it would print the new word 'phine'.

Comment: oook. What have you tried in order to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace) can do this natively:

```
<?php
    $a = array('jo', 'se');
    $word = 'josephine';

    $word = str_replace($a, '', $word);
    var_dump($word); //string(5) "phine"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/zbaz0CNK)

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I'll accept this as the solution after 11 minutes have passed.

Answer (score 0):

[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$a = array('jo', 'se'); 
$word= 'josephine';
echo str_replace($a, '', $word);
```

or using [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/strtr)

```
echo strtr($word, $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in the manual

```
$a = array('jo', 'se');
$word= 'josephine';
$string = str_replace($a, "", $word);
```

> mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
>
> This function returns a string or an array with all occurrences of search in subject replaced with the given replace value.